# Animation on opportunity closed won status

Tags: javascript, opportunity, action

Is there a way to show some animation on the page once an opportunity is set to closed won status? I'd like to have some animation like money falling or fireworks to keep the sales team motivated once they close a deal.

Comment: Is it standard SF or you have built something custom?

Comment: We have a standard enterprise instance of SFDC. I was able to configure process builder to show a pop up message to the effect of "Congrats!" but we would like to step it up a notch and somehow incorporate some visuals. Not sure where to begin or if it is even feasible.

Comment: Theoretically anything is possible if you override the page with a vf page or in lightning, create a lightning component. I'm curious as to how you got the process builder to display a pop up... Also, are your sales reps children? Or, did we somehow travel back to 1995?

Comment: @gNerb We used quick action in process builder along with posting to chatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a big fan of heavy coding or building components for UX purpose. But you can do something quickly using a formula field.

Create a formula field on opportunity, won formula provide the following its content.

```
Text(StageName )=='Closed Won',IMAGE("https://media2.giphy.com/media/13n4Hd98ewKJsQ/giphy.gif","100"),"")
```

As soon as the opportunity is won, you can see fireworks.

[image]

Comment: @Dennis If this works for you please remember to select it as the answer.